# How to pass values from ID (like name etc. from Active Directory) to list, and save it in another list (C#)?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have to get information from AD using, for example, list with IDs. The following code has to read that lists value, write  down what is connected with it (name, mail,organization etc.) and save it in another list. 
Here is what I have written so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PrincipalContext domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, null);
        UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(domainContext);
        List<string>id = new List<string>();
        id.Add("someid");
        id.Add("someid");
        id.Add("someid");
        user.Name = id[2];
        Console.ReadLine();
        PrincipalSearcher pS = new PrincipalSearcher();
        pS.QueryFilter = user;
        PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> results = pS.FindAll();
        Principal pc = results.ToList()[0];
        DirectoryEntry de = (DirectoryEntry)pc.GetUnderlyingObject();
        var userData = new Data();
        userData.ID = de.Properties["samAccountName"].Value.ToString();
        userData.name = de.Properties["givenName"].Value.ToString();
        userData.lastName = de.Properties["sn"].Value.ToString();
        userData.mail = de.Properties["mail"].Value.ToString();
        userData.organization = de.Properties["extensionAttribute2"].Value.ToString();
        List<Data> d = new List<Data>();
        d.Add(userData);
```

And the class Data:

```
  public class Data
    {

        public string name { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public string mail { get; set; }
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string organization { get; set; }
        //public Data() { }
    }
}
```

I can not really come up with solution - how to pass the values and save them.

Comment: Does the existing code work to get what you need out of Active Directory? and when you say pass to another list, it seems you are already doing that with your List of Data objects. Where do you need to pass the values to?

Comment: Could you actually read data from AD? If yes, where exactly are you trying to save the data to? Trying to update AD itself or what?

Comment: Hi, the code works correctly for one ID (for exmple if I write userName = "idnumber", and the do the foreach loop). The problem is I don't know how to do the same for 3 or 4 IDs in a list. The values after all have to be passed to another list (d in my example) and saved.

Comment: For each new Data class you need to perform : var userData = new Data(); d.Add(userData);

Comment: I thought about creating two methods - first one saving the list of strings, and a second one to transfer and save them in d list. So far it's just a clue.

Comment: @Kuba Did you have the chance to check my answer?

Comment: @uteist, hi, yup, did it, but the info from AD does not get into the list, so the loop is useless. Still thinking about the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I hope I got the issue correctly.
Considering you got your code working properly for 1 user and need to add other users to the list here's what you need:

```
        List<string> idList = new List<string>();
        idList.Add("someid");
        idList.Add("someid");
        idList.Add("someid");
        List<Data> d = new List<Data>();
        foreach (string id in idList)
        {
            user.Name = id;
            PrincipalSearcher pS = new PrincipalSearcher();
            pS.QueryFilter = user;
            PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> results = pS.FindAll();
            Principal pc = results.ToList()[0];
            DirectoryEntry de = (DirectoryEntry)pc.GetUnderlyingObject();
            var userData = new Data();
            userData.ID = de.Properties["samAccountName"].Value.ToString();
            userData.name = de.Properties["givenName"].Value.ToString();
            userData.lastName = de.Properties["sn"].Value.ToString();
            userData.mail = de.Properties["mail"].Value.ToString();
            userData.organization = de.Properties["extensionAttribute2"].Value.ToString();
            d.Add(userData);
        }
```

Basically, you just loop through every id in your -to be created- idList, assign each id it to user.Name, do your usual AD stuff and finally add each userData to data list.

Comment: Ok, the solution was to create a method:'    public static  List<Data> listConvert (List<string> idList)' and than just after the loop do return d.

Comment: And how exactly that differs from my suggestion, besides putting it in a method?
In my answer, in the end you will have List `d` which includes all data you need anyways.

Comment: It does not differ, you just have to put that code into method and that's all. But it took me a while to understand it, and to make it work the right way. Anyway, thank you for your help @uteist !

Comment: @Kuba I'm glad it helped. Could you mark it as answer?